# Calculating Pi in python without modules

Tags: python-3.x, pi

I'm trying to calculate the first 1000 digits of pi without using any modules. Every formula of calculating Pi I have seen until is using functions that can only be approached by the math module like calculating an infinite series or use integrals.
Does someone have an idea about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80):

```
>>> def leibniz(n):
    pi = 1
    for i in range(1, n):
        pi += ((-1) ** i) * (1 / (2 * i + 1))
    return pi * 4

>>> leibniz(5)
3.3396825396825403
>>> leibniz(10000)
3.1414926535900345
>>> leibniz(100000)
3.1415826535897198
>>> leibniz(10000000)
3.1415925535897915
```

Comment: With regular floating point arithmetic, you cannot possibly calculate pi to 1000 decimals, as OP wants. But add `import decimal; decimal.getcontext().prec = 1000`, then change `pi = 1` to `pi = decimal.Decimal(1)` and `(1 / (2 * i + 1))` to `(decimal.Decimal(1) / (2 * i + 1))`, and now we're getting somewhere. Sure, that's using a Python module... the alternative is to program your own fixed point arithmetic, I suppose? :P